# Inactive button not readable when reviewing First Posts or Late Answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review-page

When reviewing First Posts or Late Answers, the inactive button is hardly visible:

[image]

This seems to be Ask Different-specific, it doesn't happen on a dozen other sites I checked.

I've tested this on the latest Safari and Firefox on macOS 10.13.3.

Comment: All other blue buttons changed in style too very slightly throughout AD when this bug occurred, seems related to a CSS revision yesterday

Comment: I've noticed this recently and was starting to open a new question but found this instead. Noticed it on Firefox, Win10. Also recall the problem on Safari MacOS High Sierra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [new site theme](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3327/121968) has fixed this problem:

[image]